# How do I create an HLS master playlist with ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

There is a command that generates hls videos in different sizes.
Now I need to merge them into one master playlist. ([What is a master playlist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/creating_a_primary_playlist)) How do I do this? What and where do I need to add in this command?

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i input.mp4 \
  -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_segment_filename output/360p_%03d.ts output/360p.m3u8 \
  -vf scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename output/480p_%03d.ts output/480p.m3u8 \
  -vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename output/720p_%03d.ts output/720p.m3u8 \
  -vf scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_segment_filename output/1080p_%03d.ts output/1080p.m3u8
```

What I am interested in is the automatic creation of a master playlist using ffmpeg in this command.

## UPD: I answered my own question

After several attempts, I still got the desired result. I modified the command and now it looks like this

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
  -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -c:a aac -ar 48000 \
  -filter:v:0 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:0 856k -bufsize:v:0 1200k -b:a:0 96k \
  -filter:v:1 scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:1 1498k -bufsize:v:1 2100k -b:a:1 128k \
  -filter:v:2 scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:2 2996k -bufsize:v:2 4200k -b:a:2 128k \
  -filter:v:3 scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:3 5350k -bufsize:v:3 7500k -b:a:3 192k \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3" \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -hls_list_size 0 \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  -hls_segment_filename output/%v_%03d.ts output/%v.m3u8
```

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you can share the answer below; Sharing the answer in the question will not be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several attempts, I still got the desired result. I modified the command and now it looks like this

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
  -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -c:a aac -ar 48000 \
  -filter:v:0 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:0 856k -bufsize:v:0 1200k -b:a:0 96k \
  -filter:v:1 scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:1 1498k -bufsize:v:1 2100k -b:a:1 128k \
  -filter:v:2 scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:2 2996k -bufsize:v:2 4200k -b:a:2 128k \
  -filter:v:3 scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:3 5350k -bufsize:v:3 7500k -b:a:3 192k \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3" \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  -hls_segment_filename output/%v_%03d.ts output/%v.m3u8
```

Comment: when i tried this command in nodejs    ' cannot be applied to output url uploads/output.m3u8 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for output file uploads/output.m3u8.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument '.  This error occur

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone facing an issue with the above command.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0   -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -c:a aac -ar 48000   -filter:v:0 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:0 856k -bufsize:v:0 1200k -b:a:0 96k   -filter:v:1 scale=w=960:h=540:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:1 1498k -bufsize:v:1 2100k -b:a:1 128k   -filter:v:2 scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:2 2996k -bufsize:v:2 4200k -b:a:2 128k   -filter:v:3 scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:3 5350k -bufsize:v:3 7500k -b:a:3 192k   -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:1080p v:1,a:1,name:720p v:2,a:2,name:540p v:3,a:3,name:360p" -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "v%v/segment%d.ts" v%v/index.m3u8
```

**Full text-**

> ffmpeg -hide_banner -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0
> -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0   -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -c:a aac -ar 48000   -filter:v:0 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:0
> 856k -bufsize:v:0 1200k -b:a:0 96k   -filter:v:1
> scale=w=960:h=540:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:1
> 1498k -bufsize:v:1 2100k -b:a:1 128k   -filter:v:2
> scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:2
> 2996k -bufsize:v:2 4200k -b:a:2 128k   -filter:v:3
> scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:3
> 5350k -bufsize:v:3 7500k -b:a:3 192k   -var_stream_map
> "v:0,a:0,name:1080p v:1,a:1,name:720p v:2,a:2,name:540p
> v:3,a:3,name:360p" -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls -hls_time 10
> -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "v%v/segment%d.ts" v%v/index.m3u8